# How to view logs for Azure web app for container?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-monitoring

I am struggling with setting up logging for my container web app in Azure. What I would like to view is basically all traffic going back and forth, so JSON input and output and exceptions and the like. So I guess just Application Insights, but for containers.

I have read through I think all of Microsoft's documentation on Azure container monitoring solution, but found no step-by-step guide on how to set it up. One guide explains how to set up a new web app, but I already have an existing web app that I want to link to a new monitoring solution. Some guides explain how to set it up for AKS, but I don't have AKS.

I found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-collect-azurevm, but I am not sure if it is exactly what I am looking for. I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction here, because I have clicked what feels like every single button in Azure portal, but no logs are showing up. I have obviously tried to add a container monitoring solution with a log analytics workspace, but how do I connect this to my container web app?

Comment: what type of webapp is? If you include the AppInsights SDK into a MVC then you will see the calls independently from the container. In Visual Studio you can right click Add-> Application Insights, and then when you deploy the app you need to make sure that you are passing the right app insight key

Comment: I have two web apps I would like logs for. One .NET web api and one Vue frontend.

Comment: Also, Application Insights is deprecated and not recommended to use for containers.

Answer (score 1):

Checked the logs in container settings.

[image]

This is also explained in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245077/where-can-i-find-docker-container-logs-for-azure-app-service).

Comment: This is a possibility of course, but it's not a very good way to view the logs and it has no way to search for anything.