# Docker container logs for Azure App service is not seen

Tags: azure, docker, logging

Whenever I would like to see the Logs for my Dockerized App which is running in Azure App Service, I get the below screen.

[image]

Can anyone help on this to see the logs of app deployment?

Comment: Did you see the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245077/where-can-i-find-docker-container-logs-for-azure-app-service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stream the application logs you first need to enable them. Click on the **App Service Logs** menu, set a max size and a retention period and enable the logs.